# Getting 302 redirects when testing website on pingdoms and others

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I am not able to identify how and where it is happening. When i run a test on pingdom, every 3 out of 5 times it will show in the result that my website www.filliplingua.com is redirected to "/". I am giving the link to the reults below:

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bpgda9/www.filliplingua.com

It is a joomla website. I even reset my .htaccess. And turned off redirect plugin in joomla and cleared all kinds of caches. Still it is showing. Can u please help me find out how to solve is.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect is originating from PHP it's programmed with the `header()` function, and that function will throw a warning if the output has already started, because the first output will send the HTTP headers.

[PHP Manual about header():](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

So what you can do in `index.php` is start the file with any output, like `echo "here";`

and this will trigger a warning when the script is trying to redirect, the redirect will fail, and in the error description (in the log or on the page, depending on your error-reporting settings) you will be able to see what file the redirect originates from. From there, you will probably figure out why it tries to redirect.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. thnx for the reply. I tried doing what u said but i get no errors. I added the echo line and tried find out but there are no errors. Apart from PHP what other reasons can there be???

Comment: Try clearing browser caches. The redirect could be in your browser cache. If this doesn't help the issue is certainly not at PHP level. Check webserver configuration next.

Comment: I tired everything but failed. I am so tired about this issue. I dont know what to do. :(

Comment: Strange issue. Pingdom reports being redirected two times to the same URL and then it receives the markup from the same URL.